# Windows and Linux on LXD

Tags: lxd

Can different flavors of Windows or Linux (just 1 instance) run on LXD ? Any specific considerations ? (performance/scale/Openstack integration among others)

Answer (score 3):

Linux, yes. Containers are chroots, not VMs though, so you cannot run other incompatible operating systems. You need a VM to run Windows on top of Ubuntu or any other Linux.

As for other distributions on top of Ubuntu (or any other distribution running LXD), everything will generally work as long as you're wanting to run a compatible architecture (i386 on i386, or amd64 or i386 on amd64, for example). Anything which needs specific kernel features which may not be enabled in the host system, won't work inside the container, as it's not a VM.

If you need VMs, you'll need Openstack and similar to run VM images instead of LXC/LXD containers.